# Is there something like CherryPy or Cerise in the Java world?

Tags: java, python

[CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) and [Cerise](http://cerise.rubyforge.org/) are two small frameworks that implement nothing but the barebones of a web-framework and I love their simplicity: in fact I reckon that if Classic ASP was implemented that way (and didn't pretty much *require* VBScript) I could have settled for it and lived happily ever after.

But now I'm living at the borders of the Java world and would like to know if there's something similar to these 2 frameworks and that doesn't try to take control away from you. My requrements would be that they have an:

- a dispatcher that maps urls to methods (like CherryPy, Django, Cerise, Rails, etc...)
- bonus points if it has a simple, yet powerful templating language (a la JSP/ASP) that is not too religious in separation of concerns
- bonus points if it has some sort of library that helps in validating forms

Thanks

--

Comment: ASP is language independant; you can install python and use it in ASP.

Answer (score 2):

[Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home)

URLs to methods, check, form validation, check.  Powerful but stays out of your way unless you need it.

Answer (score 2):

[OOWeb](http://ooweb.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html), essentially a port of CherryPy.

Comment: Nice one, will give it a look!

Answer (score 0):

Groovy and [Grails](http://www.grails.org). If you like MVC or even have a existing library written in Java/JVM, that are the tools you're looking for!

> Grails aims to bring the "coding by
>   convention" paradigm to Groovy. It's
>   an open-source web application
>   framework that leverages the Groovy
>   language and complements Java Web
>   development. You can use Grails as a
>   standalone development environment
>   that hides all configuration details
>   or integrate your Java business logic.
>   Grails aims to make development as
>   simple as possible and hence should
>   appeal to a wide range of developers
>   not just those from the Java
>   community.

Comment: Don't particularly like the Rails approach of conventions over configuration: i come from Python land and prefer explicit. My opinion is that they pushed DRY to far in Rails to the point it backfired.