# Can Restlet be used to approximate the behavior of CherryPy

Tags: java, rest, restlet, cherrypy

I've been looking at Restlet for a few hours and can't seem to make head or tails out of it.

I was looking for a framework that I could use to approximate the behavior or CherryPy.

I see a previous StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610516/is-there-something-like-cherrypy-or-cerise-in-the-java-world) which lists OOWeb and Strips as possible Java equivalents to CherryPy -- it's an old question and I'm not sure of the current state of these two frameworks.

What I really want to do is to implement this interface:

```
public interface ArithmaticResource {

@Get("json")
public int add (int n0, int n1);

@Get("json")
public int add (int n0, int n1, int n2);
}
```

And, allow it to be invoked using a cURL like interface -- perhaps OOWeb would be a better fit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve looks like an RPC interface than a REST design, but you could try this with Restlet:

```
public interface ArithmaticResource {

@Get("json?n0&n1")
public int add ();

@Get("json?n0&n1&n2")
public int add ();
}
```

Comment: I actually am, yes RPC but using a REST semantics (hope that makes sense). Very interesting on what you did ... do u have a reference to the docs which explains what that will do. Thanks again